# ' entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext -CoreData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I am getting this error when running the app:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:

'+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity

name 'Event''
```

This is my TimeTableController.h file (TimeTableController is a subclass UITableViewController and app loads this file when app stared.

TimeTableController.h:

```
#import "Event.h" 

@interface TimeTableController : UITableViewController
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
    NSMutableArray *eventArray;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *eventArray;
- (void) fetchRecords;
- (void) addTime:(id)sender;

@end
```

Event.h and Event.m are my model files.

And TimeTableController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Lap Times";
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addTime:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    //[addButton release];
    [self fetchRecords];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

-(void)fetchRecords {
    // This line gives the error
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

}
```

The line in fetchRecords method is giving the error.

And this is my AppDelegate.m file:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    TimeTableController *tableController = [[TimeTableController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableController.managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tableController];
    //[tableController release];
    [window addSubview: [self.navigationController view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

When I've created the project,Data Model file didn't exist so I've added the Data Model file (LapTimer.xcdatamodeld) to existing project.

I tried all solutions I found and I have no idea why I am getting this error now.

Note: I know there are a lot of threads that cover exactly this questions. I looked at all but none of answers didn't work for me.

Comment: Has your AppDelegate managedObjectContext been instantiated? My guess is it's nil when you assign it to the tableController's managedObjectContext.

Comment: Yes, it has. I don't why but started to work great after restarted XCode.

Comment: Xcode occasionally hiccups like that.

Answer (score -1):

I was getting the same error message and it turns out that managedObjectContext was nil.

Comment: er - isn't that exactly what the error messages is saying anyway?

Comment: I wanted to say that managedObjectContext wasn't properly initialized before getting entity description. I know that message is self-explanatory but in my case it wasn't obvious that managedObjectContext isn't initialized. In code above probably managedObjectContext property is not initialized inside AppDeelegate.m file and I'm guessing that managedObjectContext getter isn't performing lazy initialization.